# Использование массива нулевого размера

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Меня всегда интересовало, почему компилятор ругается на эту ошибку и как ее исправить.

```
struct A{ int size; unsigned char data[0]; };
```

warning C4200: нестандартное расширение: массив нулевого размера в структуре (объединении)

Используется эта структура так:

```
A *a = (A*) malloc(1024);
a->size = 1024 - sizeof(A);
```

Нулевой размер используется для того, чтобы sizeof возвращала только размер структуры, без лишних данных. Для исправления ошибки можно убрать переменную data, но тогда будет сложнее обращаться к ней.

Использовать unsigned char *data, тоже не вариант, так как придется либо выделять новый блок памяти, либо указывать в data на область памяти сразу за структурой.

Вот и получается, что это предупреждение никак не исправить. Или все же есть варианты?

Comment: Так это же предупреждение (что понятно), а не ошибка. Либо игнорируйте, либо запретите этот тип диагностики соответствующей прагмой или ключами компилятора. P.S. а `c++` тут каким боком?

Comment: А в чем сложность обращения к data, если там будет unsigned char*?

Comment: Сложности нет. А может быть, например, желание избежать излишней фрагментации памяти. Абсолютно стандартное решение для этого случая.

Comment: BTW, можно просто объявлять массив с ненулевым размером, хуже не станет: `struct A{ int size; unsigned char data[1]; };`

Comment: Вот, кстати, по теме: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx

Comment: Вы используется т.н. "хак", поведение которого вполне понятно на том компиляторе, который Вы используете(оно должно быть описано), поэтому надо просто отключить `warning` и забыть про это.

Answer (score 8):

Компилятор ругается потому, массивы нулевого размера запрещены стандартом.

[Некоторые компиляторы](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) разрешают это, но не все.

Проблема с массивами нулевого размера такая же, как и с любыми объектами нулевого размера: *адреса разных объектов **должны** быть разными*. Это (неявное) предположение используется большим количеством кода.

Имея объекты *нулевого* размера, легко нарушить это правило.

---

Для случая массива переменного размера в конце структуры используется так называемый [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html), на который вам уже указывали. В нём массив объявляется просто как `array[]`, без указания размера. Это и есть ответ на вопрос, как правильно исправить:

```
struct A{ int size; unsigned char data[]; };
```

Это решение, однако, требует компиляции языком C, А не C++, как правильно отметил @ixSci.

---

Visual Studio (по крайней мере 2013-ая) компилирует код как C++. Несмотря на то, что в стандарте C++ такого нет, этот код компилируется, но выдаётся предупреждение, что не может быть создан копирующий конструктор. Это и правильно, так как правильный копирующий конструктор невозможен. Вы можете подавить это предупреждение при помощи

```
#pragma warning(suppress : 4200)
struct A { int size; unsigned char data[]; };
```

---

Не забудьте, что *правильное* использование структуры со flexible array member'ом — вычисление требуемого размера в рантайме и выделение её через `malloc` с указанием правильного размера.

Comment: эти строки, по сути, равнозначны и студия на Ваш вариант будет ругаться точно так же.

Comment: @ixSci: Студия — да, но standard-compilant compiler — нет.

Comment: Standard-compliant **C** compiler. А у автора мало того, что C++, так ещё и студия.

Comment: @ixSci: Проверил в студии. Всё прекрасно компилируется. Выдаётся правильный warning со объяснением: "Cannot generate copy-ctor or copy-assignment operator when UDT contains a zero-sized array".

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/18I52aUm - то же предупреждение, что и в вопросе. У меня 2013 студия.

Answer (score 4):

Массивы нулевого размера запрещены потому что размер всех объектов должен быть больше единицы, чтобы у каждого объекта был свой уникальный адрес.

Для решения Вашей задачи обычно используют следующий код:

```
struct A { int size; };

unsigned char* data(A* a) {
  return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(a + 1);
}

A* create_A(int size) {
  A* a = (A*)malloc(size + sizeof(A));
  a->size = size;
  return a;
}
```

В случае, если нужен массив из элементов, тип которых отличается от `[unsigned] char`, надо учитывать выравнивание. Для этого надо использовать спецификатор `alignas`:

```
template<typename T>
struct alignas(T) A {
  std::size_t size;

  T* data() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this + 1); };
};
```

Использование массива из одного элемента, чтобы хранить произвольное количество элементов, например

```
struct A { int size; unsigned char data[1]; };
```

не рекомендуется, т.к. статические анализаторы будут выдавать ошибки, если увидят чтение за концом массива.

Comment: [Вот почему](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx) так нельзя. Выравнивание же!

Comment: И как в этом варианте обращаться к "полю" `a.data`? Его же просто нет :-)

Comment: Соглашусь, приведено хреновое решение, даже без учета выравнивания. Вариант с ANYSIZE_ARRAY и то лучше.

Comment: @Abyx: Окей, беру категоричное заявление назад. В данном случае можно. Но в общем случае всё равно нельзя. Ну и если кто-то увидит такой код и скопирует, будет потом нас ругать.

Comment: @Abyx: А, я понял, моя ошибка, вопрос снимается.

Comment: @Abyx: А не потребуем ли мы излишний alignment для структуры? Может ли быть случай, когда alignment члена структуры сильнее, чем alignment самой структуры?

Comment: "*статические анализаторы будут выдавать ошибки*" - IMHO, очевидно, что любые сообщения чего угодно нужно анализировать головой. А `cppcheck`, кстати, в режиме `all` на такое даже не обращает внимания :)

Answer (score 1):

Начиная со стандарта C99, для этого правильно использовать [flexible array member](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html):

```
struct f1 {
    int x; int y[];
} f1 = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };
```

Современные версии MSVC эту возможность поддерживают.

Насколько я понимаю, массивы нулевого размера так и остались компиляторным расширением и в стандарт не вошли.

Comment: Ответ как бы совсем из другой области и не отвечает на вопрос. Здесь компилятор сам подставляет нужный размер.

Comment: Я ответил на поставленный вопрос. Компилятор показывает предупреждение потому, что использованная конструкция является нестандартной. Соответствующую стандартную конструкцию я привёл. Если б вы удосужились ознакомиться с документацией по ссылке, то владели бы семантикой данной конструкции и увидели бы, что она аналогично предложенному коду.

Comment: BTW, в тегах `visual-c++` стоит, а него с поддержкой C99 вообще очень хреново.

Comment: Вообще-то там более-менее с поддержкой C++11, поэтому, как следствие, и с C99 местами.

Comment: @ForNeVeR, Слишком много букв для ответа: unsigned char data[1];

Comment: C++11 не является надмножеством C99 и `flexible array member` в C++  не существует.

Comment: @ixSci, да, вы правы, спасибо за уточнение.