# Как создать ассерт времени компиляции(аналог static_assert) в C?

Tags: c, компиляция, отладка

В некоторых ситуациях для облегчения обнаружения и исправления ошибок в программе может потребоваться сделать несколько утверждений об истинности/ложности какого-то выражения, не только во время выполнения, но и во время компиляции.

В С++ для этого [применяется static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Примеры:

Утверждение о версии подключенной библиотеки:

```
#include "SomeLibrary.h"

static_assert(SomeLibrary::Version > 2, "Старые версии SomeLibrary не поддерживаются, используйте новые.");
```

Утверждение о количестве бит в unsigned int:

```
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT == 32, "Компиляция на неподдерживаемой платформе");
```

Как создавать подобные утверждения в обычном C, где есть только ассерты времени выполнения в виде [макроса из assert.h](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h)?

Comment: здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c

Comment: Просто перенес [не слишком удачный ответ из этого треда в отдельный](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426296/Использование-массива-нулевого-размера/426308#426308).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать любую ошибку компиляции, например структуры с битовыми полями отрицательного размера:

```
#define CT_ASSERT_NULL(x) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(x); }))
#define CT_ASSERT_ZERO(x) sizeof(struct { int: -!!(x); }))
#define CT_ERROR sizeof(struct { int: -1;});
```

Кроме того такая [функция добавлена, начиная со стандарта C11](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853) и в gcc-4.6 теперь можно делать так:

```
_Static_assert( sizeof(int) == sizeof(long int), "Error!");
```