# Си. Незавершенные массивы в структурах

Tags: c

Пишу записную книжку на си для самообучения. Не пойму, как корректно для си реализовать структуру:

```c
struct entry {
  long int length;
  struct entry *prev;
  struct entry *next;
  char tag[];  // 
  char text[]; //
}
```

Этот вариант компилятор не переваривает и вроде понятно почему. Вопрос в том, как корректно и просто в структуру запихнуть два незавершенных текстовых массива и можно ли. С указателями и встроенными структурами свзываться не хотелось бы. Честно говоря, даже не знаю в какую сторону копать.

ps
Я имел ввиду не с указателями как таковыми, а с конструкциями типа

```
struct _entry { char *text[]; char *tag[];}
char text[];
char tag[];
```

С последующим запихиванием в файл всей этой цепочки.
Неправильно выразился.

Вариант решения -

```
struct _entry
{  
  char *text;     // Смещение начала текста
  char tag[1];    // Ссылка на текст
};
  char text[]="Today we give the money";
  char tag[]="Notes";
  int size_e = strlen(text)+strlen(tag)+sizeof(struct _entry);

  void *p = malloc(size_e);
  struct _entry * e = p;

  e->text = e->tag + strlen(text);
  strcpy(e->tag,tag);
  strcpy(e->text,text);

  printf ("Размер структуры %i\n", size_e);
  printf ("Структура : %p\n", e );
  printf ("Тэг : %p\n", e->tag );
  printf ("Текст : %p\n", e->text );
  printf ("Последний байт : %p\n", e+size_e);

  file=fopen(filename, "ra+");
  int i = fwrite(e , size_e, 1, file);

  free(p);
  fclose(file);
```

Вывод:

```
Размер структуры 76
Структура : 0x126f010
Тэг : 0x126f038
Текст : 0x126f04f
Последний байт : 0x126fe50
Open file f.dat... Ok
Записано 1 байт
файл:
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 f04f 0126 0000 0000 6f4e 6574 0073 0000
0000030 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5400
0000040 646f 7961 7720 2065 6967 6576          
000004c
```

Никак не соображу, откуда получается разброс между `e->tag` и `e->text`.

Comment: std::string не предлагать?

Comment: хотелось бы чистый си. С плюсами конечно проще бы было.

Comment: а что, std::string уже есть в сях?

@Guest4 - либо укажите максимальный размер Ваших строк, либо используйте правильно сишные строки через указатели.

Comment: Нельзя. И понятно, почему: откуда компилятор узнает, по какому смещению располагать `text`? Придётся делать через указатели (и быть внимательным при сериализации). Кстати, с только одним массивом неизвестной длины [сработало бы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426296/10105).

Comment: @KoVadim Указатель -  struct{ ....  char* text; char tag[];} Затем при инициализации tag="ИмяПетрПетрович" и указатель text=*tag[3]?

Comment: @Guest4 указанный код будет работать, но там есть несколько подводных камней. Если потом напишете что то вида объект.text[2] = 'a'; то будет очень весело:)

Comment: Без костылей никак не запихнуть. C это по определению вечная боль из байтовых буферов и указателей.

Comment: Стоп. Вот это: ` char *text[];  char *tag[];` совсем меняет картину и смысл... Лучше обычными словами объясните, что именно должно быть в структуре.

Comment: Полная проблема в следующем : нужна структура для записи в файл с двумя полями char с неопределенным размером (строками).

Comment: В общем случае в файл писать структуры переменной длины - нельзя. Придётся или использовать сериализацию, или что-то типа JSON, или придумывать свои варианты. Но если вы ждёте чего-то "лёгкого" типа  `fwrite(data,sizeof(data)1,file)`, или пытаетесь подогнать структуру под одну операцию чтения для всего - этого не будет. Учитесь сразу работать со сложными структурами.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, как-то  так, например:

```
typedef struct _entry 
{
  char * tag; 
  char text[1];
}*entry;

entry e = malloc( sizeof(struct _entry) + SIZE_TEXT + SIZE_TAG );
e->tag = e->text + SIZE_TEXT;
```

> С указателями и встроенными структурами свзываться не хотелось бы

Значит, надо менять язык. Так как C из этого состоит более, чем на половину.

---

Сразу не прочухал что речь о записной книжке. Как-то так, например:

```
typedef struct _entry
{
   pointer_list  tags; // список ссылок на элементы списка тегов
   char *        text; // вот тут можно поизвращаться с text[]
} entry;
```

То есть хранить теги в отдельном списке строк, на элементы которого ссылаются указатели в `entry.tags` Второй вариант: хранить теги в динамическом массиве, а в `entry` - список индексов в нём. А уж как хранить все структуры `entry` - вопрос способов применения. Думаю, динамического массива будет достаточно.

Так что без указателей в C - никуда :)

Comment: Спасибо! Сижу разбираюсь.

Comment: Разберитесь лучше с вопросом "зачем вам это"? Потому как областей оправданного применения такого подхода очень мало. И люди, которые с этими областями знакомы, подобных вопросов не задают :-) Во всех остальных случаях этот подход не просто не нужен, а может и вредить.

Comment: Меня в общем интересует анализ естественного языка. Насколько я понимаю, динамические структуры для этой области свойственны.  В процессе разбора выяснилось, что strcpy(text,e->text) записывает текст в какую-то непонятную область структуры e. Такое впечатление, что компилятор выравнивает e по каким-то блокам. Возможно strcpy не то что нужно, чтобы занести массив char в структуру?

Comment: Код `strcpy(text,e->text)` делает ровно то, что и должен делать. Если у вас получается что-то другое, то что-то вы делаете неправильно. Для подробностей нужен полный контекст.

Comment: Судя по обновлению поста  - рано ещё к сложным структурам переходить, сначала надо бы в самых основах C разобраться...

Answer (score 2):

*ТС тут вся система прогнила©* Надо менять:

1. Двусвязный список для записной книжки это немного не та структура данных. Что например случится с ней если потребуется отсортировать записи не по дате добавления, а по меткам? Придется пересчитывать каждый раз указатели после перестановки. Обычный динамический массив сойдет.
2. В двух разных записях могут быть одинаковые метки. Поэтому их надо хранить в отдельном массиве, а в самом entry только их индексы. Либо создать отдельный массив объектов для связи 1 - много между метками и записями.
3. `long int` неправильный тип данных для длины массива(оно может внезапно стать отрицательным), нужен `size_t` или `uint64_t`.

По поводу самого вопроса, то советую привыкнуть. C программы, это в 99% случаев мессиво из буферов и указателей.

Самое простое решение насильственно статически ограничить длину текста отдельной записи.

Либо где-то в начале создать один буфер для хранения текста всех записей и добавлять еще буферов если записей становится слишком много.

```
(текст 1, текст 2 ... текст MAX_PER_BUFFER)[буфер 1]

(текст MAX_PER_BUFFER+1,текст MAX_PER_BUFFER+2 ... текст MAX_PER_BUFFER+MAX_PER_BUFFER)[буфер 2]

...

(текст MAX_BUFFERS*MAX_PER_BUFFER+1,текст MAX_BUFFERS*MAX_PER_BUFFER+2 ... , текст MAX_BUFFERS*MAX_PER_BUFFER+MAX_PER_BUFER)[буфер MAX_BUFFERS]
```

Вариант одна запись(entry) - один вызов `malloc()` это ужасная ересь.

Comment: Внезапно падают метеориты. На самом деле знаковый int (который, по логике задачи не должен быть отрицательным) *это хорошее решение* -- позволяет находить ошибки в программах т.к. провоцирует "внезапные"  segmentation fault и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вам подойдет что-то вроде этого

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct data {
  struct data *next, *prev;
  int datasize, taglen;
  char data[];
#define TAG(p)  ((char *)((p)->data))
#define TEXT(p) ((char *)((p)->data + (p)->taglen + 1))
};

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct data *d = (typeof(d))malloc(sizeof(*d) + 20);
  d->datasize = 20;
  strcpy(TAG(d), "tag-1");
  d->taglen = sizeof("tag-1");
  strcpy(TEXT(d), "text-1");

  printf("sizeof(struct data) = %d\n"
         "size(*d) = %d\n"
         "d->datasize = %d\n"
         "TAG:  [%s] (%d bytes)\n"
         "TEXT: [%s] (%d bytes)\n", 
         (int)sizeof(*d), (int)(d->datasize + sizeof(*d)), d->datasize,
         TAG(d), (int)strlen(TAG(d)), TEXT(d), (int)strlen(TEXT(d)));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Что непонятно -- спрашивайте в комментариях к ответу.

Comment: Изящный выход, кстати.

Comment: Один буфер на метку и текст с макросом указателем.  Тоже плюсанул.  По поводу того что знаковые переменные для хранения размера это нормально порадовала идея, не думал так раньше. Действительно неочевидно что хуже segmentation fault от отрицательного размера буфера или случайная аллокация 100500 мБ памяти большим числом.

Comment: @avp ->struct data *d - ругается компилятор и я не пойму, почему:  
struct.c:65:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]  
   struct data *d = (typeof(d)) malloc(sizeof(*d) + 20);  
                    ^<br/>
struct.c:65:32: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘malloc’<br/>
   struct data *d = (typeof(d)) malloc(sizeof(*d) + 20);<br/>

Comment: @Guest4, я проверял в gcc и g++ в Linux. / С другими не знаю. / Скорее всего компилятор не знает `typeof(d)`, Просто уберите его для Си (или сразу замените на  явное приведение типа -- `(struct data *)` для крестов). / А может быть у Вас malloc() описан не в stdlib.h

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор должен знать размер структуры и смещение всех ее элементов сразу после ее определения. В вашем случае у него такой возможности нет. Поэтому смиритесь и используйте указатели. Для изучения C это самое то :)

Если вы хотите любой ценой избежать вызова malloc, есть варианты:

- Задайте максимальный размер ваших массивов
- Храните указатели на строки, но записывайте их друг за другом в большой статический массив
- Храните указатели на строки, хранящиеся в буфере внутри самой структуры. Размер буфера вычисляйте при выделении места под структуру на стеке, используйте `union { char[n]; struct foo; }`. Это извращение работает только в C99

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня цель именно в динамической структуре. С malloc и прочим.

Comment: @Guest4 тогда массивы - не ваш выход. Только указатели. В C массивы - это именно массивы, выделенные на стеке или в секции статических данных. Практически при всех операциях (включая передачу в качестве параметра, даже если вы напишите `foo_t foo[]`) они неявно преобразуются к указателям. Причина - в том, что компилятор должен иметь возможность всегда правильно вычислить размер массива: выражение `sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0])` всегда должно быть равно числу элементов массива, что нельзя обеспечить при передаче его в качестве параметра, не передавая размер явно.

Answer (score 0):

OK, давайте разбирать получившийся код. Ошибка уже в этой строке:

```
int size_e = strlen(text)+strlen(tag)+sizeof(struct _entry);
```

Функция `strlen()` возвращает длину строки без завершающего 0. Правильно - так:

```
int size_e = strlen(text)+1+strlen(tag)+1+sizeof(struct _entry);
```

Соответственно:

```
e->text = e->tag + strlen(text);     // ошибка 
e->text = e->tag + strlen(text) + 1; // OK
```

Дальше:

```
printf ("Тэг : %p\n", e->tag );
printf ("Текст : %p\n", e->text );
printf ("Последний байт : %p\n", e+size_e);
```

Какую информацию вы хотели получить? Если вывести адреса указателей, то всё правильно. Но какой в ней смысл? Эти адреса, то есть их смещения от начала структуры, и так уже известны. Они точно такие, какие мы вычислили в предыдущем коде, перепроверять их не смысла. А вот вывести значения - это полезная диагностическая информация:

```
printf ("Тэг   : '%s'\n", e->tag );
printf ("Текст : '%s'\n", e->text );
```

Но самое интересное будет вот тут:

```
file=fopen(filename, "ra+");
int i = fwrite(e , size_e, 1, file);
```

OK, записали. Что вы собираетесь делать с этим файлом дальше? Если там хранятся и другие элементы списка, то с какой целью? *Вы не сможете потом прочитать этот список*. Даже одну единственную структуру и то не сможете. Потому что перед чтением у вас не будет никакой информации о её размере.

Проще всего, наверное, было бы так (осмысленность хранения тегов в строке опущу, подробности хранения элементов тоже, они сейчас не важны):

```
typedef struct _entry
{
    char tag[MAX_TAG];
    char text[MAX_TEXT];
} entry;

/* ... */

entry * next;

/* пишем структуры в файл */
next = first_entry();
while( next )
{
    fwrite( next, sizeof(e), 1, file ) );
    next = next_entry();
}

/* читаем структуры из файла */
entry e;
while( fread( &e, sizeof(e), 1, file) )
{
    next = malloc( sizeof(e) );
    memcpy( next, &e, sizeof(e) );
    add_entry( next );
}
```

Ну и ещё один недостаток вашего подхода: Подобные структуры сложно будет редактировать. Заменить строки на строки покороче получится, а вот длинней - уже нет.