# Для чего нужны массивы нулевого размера?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Подскажите, для чего они нужны?

И является ли следующий пример валидным и законным? :

```
int arr_1[0], 
    arr_2[0];

memset(arr_1, 0, sizeof(int) * 0);

memcpy(arr_1, arr_2, sizeof(int) * 0);
```

PS. Приведу более конкретный пример, где бы я хотел использовать **массивы переменной длины** с возможностью задания нулевого размера:

```
void thread_func(void *_param)
{
    const size_t di_count = ((t_param*)_param)->di_count;
    const size_t ai_count = ((t_param*)_param)->ai_count;

    uint8_t di[di_count];
    uint16_t ai[ai_count];

    while (1)
    {
        // Поддержание соединения.
        // ...

        // Известно, что (di_count || ai_count) != 0

        // Опрашиваем дискретные сигналы, если они есть.
        int d = 0;
        if (di_count > 0)
        {
            d = get_di(..., ..., di, di_count);
        }

        // Опрашиваем аналоговые сигналы, если они есть.
        int a = 0;
        if (ai_count > 0)
        {
            a = get_ai(..., ..., ai, ai_count);
        }

        // Формируем пакет с результатами опроса и добавляем его в очередь.
        pack *new_pack = create_pack(...,
                                     a || d,// Доступность объекта.
                                     di_count,
                                     di_count ? di : NULL,
                                     ai_count,
                                     ai_count ? ai : NULL);

        if (new_pack != NULL)
        {
            push_pack(..., new_pack);
        }
    }
}
```

Код сильно-пресильно упрощенный, но, надеюсь, моя идея ясна.

Так вообще делают? Я довольно часто встречаюсь с ситуациями, когда мне необходим массив переменного размера с возможным размером 0. Ясное дело, что в описанном случае обратиться к элементам массива нулевого размера нельзя, но я и не собираюсь, просто это значительно упрощает код.

В общем, корректно ли делать так, как я делаю?

Comment: пример валидная  и законная бессмыслица

Comment: Она позволяет значительно упростить обработку всяких специальных условий... Но как-то подозрительно выглядит.

Comment: Вообще, по словам [Саттера](https://herbsutter.com/2009/09/02/when-is-a-zero-length-array-okay/) , стандартом разрешены только те массивы нулевой длины, память для которых выделена в куче

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295027/array-of-zero-length

Comment: @Максим, когда  вы довольно часто встречаетесь с ситуациями, когда вам необходим массив переменного размера с возможным размером 0, то не забывайте, что вместо массива  лучше использовать подходящий стандартный контейнер (  например ,вектор, std::array...)

Comment: Я работаю с языком С.

Answer (score 10):

И в С, и в С++ запрещено объявление массивов константного нулевого размера. Такие объявления являются ошибочными с точки зрения этих языков.

Дополнительно, в С, если в точке объявления variable length array значение размера не является положительным, то поведение не определено.

Массив нулевого размера можно разве что выделить через `new[]` в С++.

---

Объявления массивов явного нулевого размера поддерживаются некоторыми компиляторами в качестве нестандартного расширения языка для облегчения реализации ["struct hack"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426296/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), хотя на самом деле можно прекрасно обойтись и без этого. В языке С, начиная с С99, для этой цели служит объявление массива без указания размера вообще.

Comment: Про **struct hack** мне известно. Является ли законным объявление локального массива переменного размера с учетом того, что размер массива может быть установлен в 0? Такой массив использоваться не будет, но это значительно упрощает код, избавляя его от описания специального поведения.

Comment: @Максим: Как сказано выше, VLA нулевого размера вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Comment: То есть, если я использую VLA, и мой код гарантированно не обращается к элементам такого массива, если массив оказался нулевого размера, это все равно UB? Где об этом написано? Я что-то не нашел...

Comment: Вот тут написано, что лишь доступ к массиву нулевой длины является UB.

Comment: Стандарт языка явно говорит "If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by *; **otherwise, each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero**. " Никакого "лишь доступ" я тут не вижу.

Comment: Относится ли это поведение к **MinGW** (который есть латентный **GCC**) или не относится?

Comment: @Максим: Не ясно, что вы имеете в виду под "относится". Относится, разумеется. Но размер VLA известен только во время выполнения, т.е. нарушение этого требования компилятором не обнаруживается, а приводит к неопределенному поведению. А неопределенным поведением является все, что угодно. Как в такой ситуации различить "относится" и "не относится"?

Comment: Стандарт C запрещает массивы нулевого размера, это понятно, но GNU С разрешает, хотя и не рекомендует использовать массивы нулевого размера вне контекста использования структур переменной длины. GNU C говорит, что неопределенным поведением является обращение к элементам массива нулевого размера. Массивы переменной длины - несколько иная вещь, но в то же время она, видимо, пересекается с массивами нулевого размера, если размер массива задан в 0. Так вот. Является ли для GNU C неопределенным поведением массив переменного размера с 0 размером, если обращения к элементам не происходит?

Comment: Я так понимаю, это достаточно мутная ситуация, и лучше вообще не использовать массивы нулевого размера, чтобы где-нибудь в непонятном месте что-то внезапно не отвалилось.