# C++ int* ptr = new int[0]

Tags: c++, указатели, new

Недавно я изучал С++ и мне попался один интересный вопрос, про что будет при выделении памяти таким образом new любой_тип_данных[0]. Как я понял из найденного материала в интернете:

1. Это абсолютно законно в С++ и будет выделена память для массива с 0 элементов.
2. С таким указателем мало что можно сделать, поскольку это приведёт к неопределённом поведению.
3. Такой указатель впоследствии нужно будет очистить с помощью оператора delete[].

Но мне остаётся не ясным то, где в реальных проектах или хотя бы учебных проектах данная операция может применятся. На этот вопрос я не нашёл какой-либо устраивающей меня информации. Кроме одного применения, когда программа вычисляет объём выделенной памяти, и если этот объём будет равен 0, не имеет смысла добавлять исключение на такой случай.

Comment: А как вам такое применение? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426296/Использование-массива-нулевого-размера

Comment: Иногда вы вычисляете длину массива некотором алгоритмом. Иногда алгоритм вычисляет нулевую длину. Разрешено выделять массивы нулевой длины, что программисту не пришлось любой код выделения памяти защищать дополнительными условными операторами.

Comment: @user_1234567890, какое отношение имеет _flexible array member_, описанный по вашей ссылке, к конструкции вида `new любой_тип_данных[0]`?

Comment: Ну, в реальной жизни, если вернули не NULL, то хоть сколько-то памяти будет выделено. В моем 64-bit Linux `malloc_usable_size()` в таком случае возвращает 24.